# Nine carpets of area $1$ on the floor of area $5$. Prove that there are two carpets which overlap by at least $1/9$

Tags: combinatorics

> Nine carpets have been put on the floor of a room of area $5$. Carpets are arbitrary shape and their area is $1$ each. Obviously, some of the carpets have to overlap. Prove that there are two carpets for which the value of overlapping area is at least $1/9$.

I'm very bad with this kind of problems. Some general advises along with solution for this particular one would be good. I tried assuming the opposite, but failed to do anything after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $9$ carpets. The maximum number of intersections we can have is $\binom{9}{2} = 36$. If the area of each intersection is less than $1/9$ then the total area of all carpets is less than:
$$
\underbrace{5}_{\text{floor area}} + \underbrace{36}_{\text{maximum number of intersections}} \times \underbrace{1/9}_{\text{maximum area of one intersection}} = 9
$$

But we know that the area of all carpets is $9$, a contradiction.