# Area of occluded carpets

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

> A room with area $4$ square meters has been covered with $7$ carpets each of which of area $1$ square meters and of arbitrary shape.Show that there are $2$ carpets that their intersection is at least $\frac17$ square meters.

Since the problem says the shape of the carpets is unspecified,I got totally confused!

Comment: Do you know about the inclusion/exclusion formula?

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes

Comment: If you look to the right of this question, in the column of information that looks like it's of no use to you, under "Related" you'll see "Nine carpets of area 1 on ...", which points to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326776/nine-carpets-of-area-1-on-the-floor-of-area-5-prove-that-there-are-two-carp?rq=1, which is essentially the same question.

Comment: @JohnHughes It is of use to me,but after asking the question! I believe the SE duplicate notification system is weak...

Comment: I agree...but a search on the keyword "carpet" also finds this. (I was going to praise you for writing the only post with the word "carpet" in the title until I found out how wrong I was...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:$$\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^7A_i\right| \geq \sum_{i=1}^7 |A_i|-\sum_{i < j \\  } |A_i \cap A_j|$$

Suppose every intersection is less than $\frac17$, prove by contradiction.

Comment: So is it related to pigeon hole principle as Frank Vel added its tag??

Comment: I think using the inclusion/exclusion is sufficient. For my approach, view $|.|$ as the area.

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Your eyes see $\ i\ne j,\ $ but your brain sees $\ i<j\ $ anyway. :)

Comment: Is there a general form of the inequality you presented?

Comment: Your brain sees $\ i<j,\ $ but your hand writes $\ i\ne j\ $ anyway.

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi, " 
Is there a general form of the inequality you presented?"

Władysław Hugo Dionizy Steinhaus would say: Consider variables: 4 and 7 and 1. ...

Comment: I would say "The inclusion exclusion formula", but I suppose others regard that as something more specialized.

Comment: If you look at the inclusion-exclusion formula, if the first $k$ summation terms are used, where $k$ is odd, it is an upperbound. If $k$ is even, it is a lower bound. For this case $k$ is $2$.  The sign is alternating in the formula because it is adjusting to improve the accuracy of over-estimation and under-estimation.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I found the general form of your inequality in a  book by K. M. Koh: it holds for $n$  sets as well,just replace 7 with $n$

Comment: Ah, the legendary Prof Koh. =)